# How to select all rows, and update field in row within the same while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to query all data, manipulate 2 of the fields to create a new value, and then update an existing field (woocat) within the same row with this new value.  It runs without error, but no updating happens.  What am I missing?

```
# Get all data
$query = "SELECT * FROM cities";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$cityid = $row['id'];
$city = $row['city'];
$state_abr = $row['state_abr'];
$state = $row['state'];

$gstate = ucwords($state);             // HELLO WORLD!
$gstate = ucwords(strtolower($gstate)); // Hello World!

$gcity = ucwords($city);             // HELLO WORLD!
$gcity = ucwords(strtolower($gcity)); // Hello World!

$woocat = ("Towns>$gstate>$gcity");

// FIX THIS to make it work
$query = "UPDATE cities SET woo_cat = '$woocat' WHERE id = '$cityid'";
mysqli_query($con, $query);
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Is the name of the table `Cities` (with the uppercase) or `cities`?

Comment: whoops.  typo. fixed.

Comment: _“It runs without error”_ - you are not _checking_ for errors anywhere. _“What am I missing?”_ - the very basics of how debugging such database issues works - so please go read up on that.

Comment: $woocat = ("Towns>$gstate>$gcity"); in that line what is the symbol (>) means ?

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the loop variable inside the loop. When you do `mysqli_query($con, $query);` you are modifying the values of `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` to the values of the new query inside the same loop, so it won't work,you can do three things:

1. Use a different connection for the first query ('select') and the second query ('update')
2. Use two loops, one to fetch the results of the select and another one to update the rows
3. Use mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC) and then loop over the results to make the update